# Jest and SCSS variables

Tags: javascript, sass, jestjs

I'm using Jest in my project and got stuck on one test which contains SCSS variable.

```
$grey-light: #C7C7C7;
```

I get this Jest error:

> Jest encountered an unexpected token

and it points on the previous mentioned line of code.

Comment: Are you compiling your scss code? Make sure you're using the compiled css and not the scss file

Comment: I'm not compiling the scss code, just import it whenever needed. BTW, it's a React project.

Comment: scss is not a valid css, the browser don't know how to read it. You need to compile it first, this will generate the css file, then you can import the generated css file.

Comment: Actually, my scss is getting compiled. It's a React project with webpack, babel etc.
The browser gets the compiled css. The only issue is with Jest.

Comment: The library I'm using for compilation is:
sass-loader

Comment: Are you using the variable in your JS files? and how/where? [Rodrigo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53907088/1218980) works well with irrelevant classnames when using CSS modules (obfuscated classes), but when using variables, we do need the values and the identity proxy is not enough.

Answer (score 8):

I ran into this as well and it was solved by using the `identity-obj-proxy` package:

https://github.com/keyz/identity-obj-proxy

Just follow the instructions in the Jest docs:

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/webpack#mocking-css-modules

And should run the tests with no issues regarding the `.scss` files import statements. All you have to do is include the jest configuration in your `package.json` file:

```json
{
  "name": "...",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "...",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack --config webpack.config.js",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(css|scss|less)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    }
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Homer Jay",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {},
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

And the `.scss` imports will work as expected and any variable or mixin won't throw an error.

Answer (score -3):

Sass helps you write more organized and maintainable code, but it's not a vaild css code, thus, browsers don't know how to read it.

scss files needs to be compiled into css, and you need to import and use the css files.
For example, the parameter you define has the `#C7C7C7` value. The compiler will replace that parameter with that value so the final css will only contain hard-coded values