# Material-UI: Jest unit tests fail because palette primary colours remain undefined in createMuiTheme function

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui

Hi I have a project in React, and am using Material UI library. In it I am wrapping some Material UI components to customise the latter. The project compiles to a library, which I will use in other app projects.

While the library compiles fine and I can actually use it successfully in my projects, some of my library unit tests are failing with the same error:

```
Material-UI: the color provided to augmentColor(color) is invalid.
The color object needs to have a `main` property or a `500` property.

  at augmentColor (node_modules/@material-ui/core/styles/createPalette.js:160:15)
  at createPalette (node_modules/@material-ui/core/styles/createPalette.js:191:14)
  at Object.createMuiTheme (node_modules/@material-ui/core/styles/createMuiTheme.js:46:44)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/theme/nr-theme.tsx:288:28)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/NrIconButton.tsx:727:25)
  at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/NrIconButton.test.tsx:6:1)
```

I traced the issue back to this piece of code

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import themeVars from './theme.scss';
export const NrTheme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        primary: {
            // will be calculated from palette.primary.main,

            //'main' and 'contrastText' are being left undefined
            // for unit tests only. As a temporal solution, they are hard-coded
            main: themeVars.buttonBlue,
            contrastText: themeVars.buttonWhite
            // main: '#006fff',
            // contrastText: '#ffffff'

        }
        /*  we can also add secondary theme property here
        *   error: will use the default color
        */
    },
    overrides: { 
        MuiButton: {
            containedPrimary: {
                '&:hover': {
                    backgroundColor: themeVars.buttonHoverBlue
                },
                '&:focus': {
                    outline: themeVars.buttonFocusOutline
                },
                textTransform: 'none'
            },
```

*main* and *contrastText* remain undefined when trying to assign them with vars from themeVars. I am using Jest framework for testing. What's funny is *main* and *contrastText* remain undefined only during unit tests; the components work as desired in the app.

Below please find my jest config

```
module.exports = {
  roots: ['__tests__'],
  testMatch: [
    '**/__tests__/**/*.+test.(ts|tsx|js)',
    '**/?(*.)+(spec|test).+test.(ts|tsx|js)'
  ],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts|tsx)?$': 'ts-jest',
    '^.+\\.svg$': 'jest-svg-transformer'
  },
  coverageDirectory: '__tests__/coverage',
  coverageThreshold: {
    global: {
      // this is a percentage
      lines: 70
    }
  },
  // we might not need this depending on how we choose to import svg's leaving here for now
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(svg)$': '<rootDir>/__tests__/svgMock.js',
    '\\.(css|less|scss)$': '<rootDir>/__tests__/styleMock.js'
  },
  modulePathIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules', 'src/theme/theme.scss']
};
```

My devDependencies in package.json

```
"@babel/cli": "^7.7.0",
"@babel/core": "^7.6.0",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.7.4",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.1",
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.7.0",
"@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.7.4",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro": "^5.11.2",
"@material-ui/core": "^4.6.1",
"@material-ui/icons": "^4.5.1",
"@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.32",
"@storybook/addon-a11y": "^5.2.6",
"@storybook/addon-actions": "^5.1.11",
"@storybook/addon-console": "^1.2.1",
"@storybook/addon-docs": "^5.2.6",
"@storybook/addon-info": "^5.1.11",
"@storybook/addon-knobs": "^5.2.6",
"@storybook/addon-links": "^5.1.11",
"@storybook/addon-viewport": "^5.2.6",
"@storybook/addons": "^5.1.11",
"@storybook/react": "^5.2.8",
"@types/jest": "^24.0.23",
"@types/node": "^12.12.7",
"@types/react": "^16.9.11",
"@types/react-dom": "^16.9.4",
"@types/storybook__react": "^4.0.2",
"autoprefixer": "^9.7.1",
"babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
"babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
"babel-plugin-inline-react-svg": "^1.1.0",
"babel-plugin-react-svg": "^3.0.3",
"cpx": "^1.5.0",
"cross-env": "^6.0.3",
"csstype": "^2.6.7",
"jest": "^24.9.0",
"jest-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
"node-sass": "^4.13.0",
"npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
"postcss-cli": "^6.1.3",
"postcss-import": "^12.0.1",
"postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
"postcss-scss": "^2.0.0",
"pretty": "^2.0.0",
"react": "^16.11.0",
"react-docgen-typescript-loader": "^3.0.1",
"react-dom": "^16.11.0",
"react-scripts": "3.2.0",
"react-svg-loader": "^3.0.3",
"rimraf": "^3.0.0",
"sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
"sass-resources-loader": "^2.0.1",
"style-loader": "^1.0.0",
"tailwindcss": "^1.1.3",
"ts-jest": "^24.1.0",
"typescript": "3.7.2",
"webpack": "^4.41.2",
"webpack-cli": "^3.3.10"
```

theme.scss:

```
$font-family: Roboto, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
$font-size-body: 0.87em;
$buttonBlue: #006fff;
$buttonHoverBlue: #007bff;
$buttonWhite: #ffffff;
$buttonFocusOutline: none;
$iconButtonGrey: #eef1f6;
$iconButtonInnerGrey: #b3b5ba;
$bottomBorderGrey: #bfbfbf;
$iconButtonHoverShadow: 0px 2px 2px 0px #b3b5ba;
$toggleButtonSelectedColor: #003478;
$toggleButtonSelectedIconColor: #ffffff;
$infoMessageColor: #005f7a;
$warningMessageColor: #faab32;
$warningBackgroundColor: #fef5f5;
$transparentColor: #ffffff00;
$borderColor: solid 1px #000000;
$underlineColor: #000000;

:export {
  buttonBlue: $buttonBlue;
  buttonHoverBlue: $buttonHoverBlue;
  buttonWhite: $buttonWhite;
  buttonFocusOutline: $buttonFocusOutline;
  iconButtonGrey: $iconButtonGrey;
  iconButtonInnerGrey: $iconButtonInnerGrey;
  bottomBorderGrey: $bottomBorderGrey;
  iconButtonHoverShadow: $iconButtonHoverShadow;
  toggleButtonSelectedColor: $toggleButtonSelectedColor;
  toggleButtonSelectedIconColor: $toggleButtonSelectedIconColor;
  infoMessageColor: $infoMessageColor;
  warningMessageColor: $warningMessageColor;
  warningBackgroundColor: $warningBackgroundColor;
  transparentColor: $transparentColor;
  borderColor: $borderColor;
  underlineColor: $underlineColor;

  fontSizeBody: $font-size-body;
}

html {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: $font-family;
}

.large {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.medium {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.small {
  font-size: 1.17em;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.xs {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

body {
  font-size: $font-size-body;
}

input[type="text"] {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.btn-md {
  width: 140px !important;
  height: 34px !important;
}

.icon-btn-md {
  width: 32px !important;
  height: 32px !important;
}

.main-header-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;

  &-icon {
    padding-right: 30px;
  }
}

.mb4 {
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.no-top-margin {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.text-truncate {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.border-none {
  border-bottom: 1px solid $transparentColor;
}

.warning-background {
  background-color: $warningBackgroundColor;
  border-bottom: 1px solid $bottomBorderGrey;
}

.fa-money-bill-wave {
  color: #02a299;
}

@tailwind utilities;
```

Any help as to how to solve this problem would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please show `theme.scss`. It seems strange to be importing an `.scss` file and then getting JavaScript variables from the result.

Comment: thx for the reply. scss file shared.

Comment: My suspicion is that your webpack configuration used when running your tests isn't supporting the JS variables exported from SCSS. If after the import you put `console.log(JSON.stringify(themeVars))` what do you get?

Comment: This may be what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52420683/jest-and-scss-variables