# Jest unable to resolve alias used in SASS file in React project

Tags: reactjs, sass, jestjs

I have been trying to figure this out. I had a lot of issues trying to setup Jest in my react project. Below are my configurations:

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const ip = require('ip');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'js/bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true,
            },
          },
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|png|svg)$/,
        loader: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            outputPath: 'images',
            name: '[name].[ext]',
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.scss'],
    alias: {
      sass: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/shared/sass'),
      src: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: path.resolve('public') }]),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: 'css/main.css' }),
  ],
  devServer: {
    open: true,
    port: 3200,
    host: ip.address(),
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    stats: 'errors-only',
  },
  stats: 'errors-only',
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "AdminPortfolio",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@nivo/line": "^0.62.0",
    "@nivo/stream": "^0.62.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.4",
    "babel-jest": "^26.2.2",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "5.1.1",
    "css-loader": "^4.2.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.2",
    "file-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "ip": "^1.1.5",
    "jest": "^26.2.2",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.9.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "sass-jest": "^0.1.7",
    "sass-loader": "^9.0.2",
    "webpack": "^4.44.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:coverage": "jest --coverage --colors"
  }
}
```

**jest.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  // Automatically clear mock calls and instances between every test
  clearMocks: true,

  // An array of glob patterns indicating a set of files for which coverage information should be collected
  collectCoverageFrom: ['src/**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}'],

  // The directory where Jest should output its coverage files
  coverageDirectory: 'coverage',

  // An array of file extensions your modules use
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'json', 'jsx', 'scss'],

  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^sass(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/shared/sass/$1',
  },

  transform: {
    '^.+\\.scss$': 'sass-jest',
    '^.+\\.(js|jsx)$': 'babel-jest',
  },

  // The paths to modules that run some code to configure or set up the testing environment before each test
  setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/enzyme.config.js'],

  // The test environment that will be used for testing
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',

  // The glob patterns Jest uses to detect test files
  testMatch: ['**/__tests__/**/*.js?(x)', '**/?(*.)+(spec|test).js?(x)'],

  // An array of regexp pattern strings that are matched against all test paths, matched tests are skipped
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['\\\\node_modules\\\\'],

  // This option sets the URL for the jsdom environment. It is reflected in properties such as location.href
  testURL: 'http://localhost',

  // An array of regexp pattern strings that are matched against all source file paths, matched files will skip transformation
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/'],

  // Indicates whether each individual test should be reported during the run
  verbose: false,
};
```

Below is the component i am testing.

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './style';

const PageHeader = ({ header }) => {
  return <div className={classes.header}>{header}</div>;
};

export default PageHeader;
```

Below is the style.scss file

```
@import 'sass/theme';
@import 'sass/mix';

.header {
  @include withTheme {
    color: useValue('c08');
  }
  font-size: pxtorem(20);
  font-weight: 400;
  padding-bottom: 35px;
}
```

And this is my test file

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import PageHeader from './index';

const setup = () => {
  const props = { header: 'Test' };
  const wrapper = shallow(<PageHeader />);
  return { props, wrapper };
};

describe('PageHeader Test Suite', () => {
  it('Should have a div', () => {
    const { wrapper } = setup();
    expect(wrapper.find('div').exists()).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

When i run the test i get the following error

```
$ jest FAIL  src/shared/components/PageHeader/PageHeader.test.js  ● Test suite failed to run
    Import error in:    /Users/raj.prem/Desktop/Random/AdminPortfolio    The import "sass/theme" could not be resolved. Searched paths:     - /Users/raj.prem/Desktop/Random/AdminPortfolio/sass/_theme.scss
     - /Users/raj.prem/Desktop/Random/AdminPortfolio/sass/theme.scss     - /Users/raj.prem/Desktop/Random/sass/_theme.scss
     - /Users/raj.prem/Desktop/Random/sass/theme.scss     - /Users/raj.prem/Desktop/Random/AdminPortfolio/src/shared/components/PageHe
ader/sass/_theme.scss     - /Users/raj.prem/Desktop/Random/AdminPortfolio/src/shared/components/PageHe
ader/sass/theme.scss     - /Users/raj.prem/Desktop/Random/AdminPortfolio/node_modules/sass-jest/sass/_theme.scss     - /Users/raj.prem/Desktop/Random/AdminPortfolio/node_modules/sass-jest/sass/
theme.scss

      at Importer.pathLookupError (node_modules/sass-thematic/lib/ast.js:256:12)
      at Importer.resolveSync (node_modules/sass-thematic/lib/ast.js:237:16)      at importFor (node_modules/sass-thematic/lib/ast.js:317:34)
      at File.parse (node_modules/sass-thematic/lib/ast.js:385:11)
      at Importer.runSync (node_modules/sass-thematic/lib/ast.js:155:17)      at Object.parseSync (node_modules/sass-thematic/lib/ast.js:407:31)      at Function.Thematic.parseASTSync (node_modules/sass-thematic/index.js:13:14)
      at Object.process (node_modules/sass-jest/transform-sass.js:226:25)
      at ScriptTransformer.transformSource (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/Sc
riptTransformer.js:463:35)
      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform
/build/ScriptTransformer.js:568:40)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 totalTests:       0 totalSnapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.306 s
Ran all test suites.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

It seems like the alias used in the scss file cannot be resolved. Can somebody guide me in setting this up to work? The test works just find when i remove the styling from the div and remove the import statement of the style.scss

Thank you.

EDIT: Or is there a way to ignore the scss since im not testing any styles. The styles are just used in the components.

Answer (score 0):

The way I've got to solve this problem importing sass|scss files was using "identity-obj-proxy", as mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53907088/10216900).

`$ npm i -D identity-obj-proxy`

```
// package.json
{
  (...)
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "start": "styleguidist server"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(css|sass)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    }
  },
 (...)
}
```